# How to receive the data via HTTP in the web service of ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http

Our team is developing an application that requires sending data from Android app to ASP.NET server via HTTP protocol and I'm in charge of the server part. I have decided to receive the data in a web service, but I don't know the specific way to do it. How do I write the web method in the asmx file to receive the data?

Comment: ASMX isn't really supported by Microsoft anymore. You would be much better sticking with something that is supported, such as [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), WCF, or simply writing an HTTP Handler.

Comment: You should go for this: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: @mason you mean web service is not supported by Microsoft anymore? Actually our project is not very large and I think web service can still meet our need.

Comment: @Ivan814 When I said ASMX isn't really supported by Microsoft anymore, that's what I meant. Bugs have been raised with that technology stack, and Microsoft has said they're not fixing bugs related to that anymore. That means it's de facto not supported. If you don't want to learn a new technology stack, then just write a generic handler, .ashx. Those are dead simple to write. You're handed a raw HTTP request and expected to handle it and write to the response directly.

Comment: @mason Could you explain it with more detail, such as which class or function should I use to retrieve the data in HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ASMX [isn't really supported anymore](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) and you want to keep it simple, write a generic handler (.ashx).

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {

    //retrieve your data from context.Request. Depending on how you choose to send the data from Android, the data may be in context.Request.QueryString or context.Request.Form or context.Request.Files. Commonly, data is sent back and forth as JSON or XML in the body. See my helper method below for retriving it

    //it's a good idea to let the client know we processed their request successfully
    context.Resonse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Success"); //this line is redundant because of the status code, but I wanted to show you how to write data to the response
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

If you want to get string data from the request body, this helper method should be handy, borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/leggetter/769688).

```
private string GetDocumentContents(HttpRequestBase Request)
{
    string documentContents;
    using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return documentContents;
}
```

If you want to get fancier, look into [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [WCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation).

Comment: Since I have no knowledge of generic handler, I'm wondering that when the android app send the http post to the server, how does it know the arrival of new http message and invoke the method to receive the data in the code you have provided? I know this can be done in web service, is it the mechanism for generic handler the same as that for web service?

Comment: @Ivan814 When you send an HTTP POST request, you provide a URL for the resource you want to POST to. So you just make sure the URL maps to your generic handler's location, for example `https://example.com/myhandler.ashx`. The framework would automatically call the `ProcessRequest` method in `myhandler.ashx`.

Comment: So that means once the android app sends the http post to the generic handler's URL location, the server immediately know it and automatically invoke the ProcessRequest method to receive the data. Is it correct?

Comment: @Ivan814 That's what I said.

Comment: I think it works and I will try it with my teammates tomorrow. Thanks a lot.